# what is the best way to sort "recently viewed pages" by date with php and cookies?

Tags: php, sorting, cookies

I am using the following code to store recently viewed pages with cookies in the user's browser and then retrieve the pages at a later time to show them.

The problem with my current way I noticed is that it will only sort the pages by ID, starting from the highest ID down but because I am showing only a maximum of 12 pages, it's not really sorting them by visit date (ie. recent ones first), but by ID.

The cookie is set like this:

```
setcookie('recently_visited['.$_REQUEST['page_id'].']', 
$_REQUEST['page_id'], time() + 86400);
```

And then retrieved via:

```
        $cookie_array = array_reverse($_COOKIE['recently_visited'], true);
        $cookie_array = array_values($cookie_array);

        for($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++){

            if(isset($cookie_array[$i])){
                $new_array[] = $cookie_array[$i];
            }

        }

        $recently_cookie = implode(",",$new_array);

        // making sure the cookie content contains only numbers

        if (ctype_digit(str_replace(",", "", $recently_cookie))) {
          $clean_string = '1';
        } else {
          $clean_string = '0';
        }

        if($recently_cookie) {

        if ($clean_string == '1'){

        // get the pages for display

        $sql_select_recent_items = $db->query("SELECT page_id, name        
        FROM db_pages WHERE page_id IN (".$recently_cookie.") LIMIT 0,12");

    }
```

What would be the easiest way to sort them, but by visit date? The most recent ones first.

I know it's not possible to get the expiration date of the cookies so that is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let SQL take care of it for you. If you're sorting by `id` then:

```
SELECT page_id, name
FROM db_pages
WHERE page_id IN (".$recently_cookie.")
ORDER BY page_id ASC
LIMIT 0,12
```

If you have an actual column for date you can alter the `page_id` accordingly. `ASC` is for ascending order, `DESC` is for descending order.

**SIDE NOTE**

Your current code opens up the possibility of SQL Injection. Handling this scenario is beyond the scope of this question, but it is well worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I'm actually trying to do is not sort by ID, but by date visited. But since I can't retrieve that from the cookie, it seems impossible right now. As for the SQL injection, please do explain a bit more as I thought I took care of that with the ctype_digit to ensure it's only numerical.

Comment: Are you able to modify the table? Perhaps one solution would be to store the date visited when the content is first accessed, and then use that information later when querying the database. This may be too large a rework, depending on your current setup.